# What's this strange error during entity_creation?

Tags: 7, entities

I'm trying to create a (no bundle) entity from a feed using entity API, but I keep running into strange issue. The code for the entities is this:

```
function my_entity_provision() {
  $a = entity_create('entityType', array(
    'pid' => NULL,
    'aid' => 1,
    ...

  ))->save();
}
```

But when running it I run into these errors:

```
Warning: class_implements() [function.class-implements]: object or string expected in entity_create() (line 420 of ...../sites/all/modules/entity/entity.module).
Warning: in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given in entity_create() (line 420 of ...../sites/all/modules/entity/entity.module).
```

I've tried looking on drupal and drupalcontrib for the correct implementation, but all code blocks show no text? :s

My code looks similar to [Create Entity Programmatically in Drupal](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29744/create-entity-programmatically-in-drupal) which does seem to work. (Since I have no bundle, I didn't define the type in the array, I read somewhere it can be omitted . But that made no difference anyway).

My entity info is as follows:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info().
 */ 
function my_entity_entity_info() {
  $return = array(
    'entityType' => array(
      'label' => t('entityType'),
      'controller class' => 'EntityAPIController',
      'base table' => 'entityTypes',
      'fieldable' => FALSE,
      'entity keys' => array(
        'id' => 'pid',
      ),
      'static cache' => TRUE,
      'view modes' => array(
        'full' => array(
          'label' => t('Full Entity'),
        ),
      ),
      'views controller class' => 'EntityDefaultViewsController',
    ),
  );

  return $return;
}
```

Comment: "in_array() expects parameter 2 to be array, boolean given" - looks like something that you should create as an array, is not an array. Sorry but can't see what is it at first glance

Comment: It is triggered by the my_entity_provision() function (it does not give an error if I don't call it). And the errors apply to entity_create. But I'm pretty sure the 2nd parameter is an array...

Comment: 2nd parameter of entity_create is, but where is that in_array used? What is passed to in_array as it's second parameter? That's the point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argh, it seems the two different entity modules (core & contrib) have confused me once again.

The EntityAPIController I chose as controller class has no method save(). It uses `entity_save($entity_type, $entity);` instead.

So the function had to be:

```
function my_entity_provision() {
  $a = entity_create('entityType', array(
    'pid' => NULL,
    'aid' => 1,
    ...

  ));
  entity_save('entityType', $a);
}
```

Comment: You might have been thinking of entities that have been extended using an `EntityMetadataWrapper`...they _do_ have the `save()` method. I believe `FieldCollection` also implements the same method on the entity controller too (maybe some other contrib modules do too)