# How to create store in commerce_store programmatically?

Tags: commerce, entities

I would like to create a store in drupal commerce_store programmatically, while I am searching for a couple of hours I realize that commerce_store is a entity type. It has bundle named store. Please see image below.....I want to add new store name My Store2 programmatically under Commerce_Store entity type.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: you want a form or using services or third party?

Comment: Hi, there's no module called commerce_store, so currently this isn't answerable. If it's a custom module you've written, provide the relevant code snippets (although if that's the case you'd probably already know how to do it). If you're dealing with entities, [this](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29744/create-entity-programmatically-in-drupal?rq=1) should have everything you need to know

Comment: yeap, there is a link (https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_marketplace) of drupal commerce marketplace, commerce_store is one its submodule, that module provides authenticated user or admin to create a store and can upload theirs products in store. My problem is I would like to create a store instance of user, without needs many steps.thks

Comment: Ok, just remember no one here can read your mind next time. See the duplicate for an answer to your question